# ¿Por qué entra en el else? Java

Tags: java, condiciones, bucles

estoy tratando de hacer un programa que cuente los números pares consecutivos que introduzca el usuario en la consola, este es mi código:

`

```
package Tarea2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SecuenciaParesMayor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        int contadorPares = 0;
        int entrada;
        
        do {
            System.out.println("Por favor, introduce un número");
            entrada = teclado.nextInt();
            if(entrada % 2 == 0) {
                contadorPares++;
            }else {
                contadorPares = 0;
            }

        }while (entrada != -1);
        
        System.out.println("La secuencia mayor de pares consecutivos es: " + contadorPares);
        
    
    }
}
```

`
Se supone que ese else resetea el contador, lo vuelve a poner en 0, ahí se rompe la secuencia y dejarían de ser consecutivos, en el momento que introducen uno impar, no obstante el programa retorna siempre 0.

He probado a quitar el else, el programa funciona bien, de no ser porque cuando introduces un numero impar, no se resetea el contador a 0, he probado con otro if pero el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: Tu programa retorna siempre cero porque el último número que ingresas es "-1", que es impar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que podes tener mas de una secuencia de numeros pares y necesitas saber la mayor secuencia podes ir agregando el tamaño de los consecutivos y guardarlo en un ArrayList y despues buscar el mayor en el:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Prueba{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
            int contadorPares = 0;
            ArrayList<Integer> consecutivos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            int entrada;
            
            do{
                System.out.println("Por favor, introduce un número");
                entrada = teclado.nextInt();
                if(entrada % 2 == 0) {
                    contadorPares++;
                }else {
                    consecutivos.add(contadorPares);
                    contadorPares = 0;
                }
    
            }while (entrada != -1);
    
            Integer i;
            contadorPares = consecutivos.get(0);
            for(i=0;i<consecutivos.size();i++){
                if(consecutivos.get(i)>contadorPares) contadorPares = consecutivos.get(i);
            }
            
            teclado.close();
            System.out.println("La secuencia mayor de pares consecutivos es: " + contadorPares);
        }
    }
```

Y al buscar al mayor uso la variable contadorPares como variable auxiliar (ya que la tengo declarada)
de este modo te va a decir siempre la secuencia mas larga de pares consecutivos independientemente de cuantas secuencias sean y de que pongas impares en el medio.
Ahora que lo pienso ni hace falta un ArrayList, solo un nuevo integer que almacene la mayor secuencia, dentro del else harias la comprobacion si la secuencia actual es mayor de la guardada la actualizarias y no tendrias que hacer el otro for.

Comment: Gracias por tu aportación, me has sido de gran ayuda, al final la idea de los ArrayList me ha gustado y simplemente he creado uno en el que se vayan almacenando las secuencias de los números pares, utilizando el metodo .add y pasandole la variable de contadorPares, luego he utilizado la clase Collections para imprimir el número mayor de ese ArrayList, con Collections.max y pasandole el arreglo.

Answer (score 0):

El problema del contador en 0, es porque cuando pones el -1 como entrada para terminar el bucle, se realiza la comprobación del bucle IF, verifica que el resultado no es 0 y salta al ELSE, entonces el contador se resetea teniendo como valor final el 0, luego entra en la comprobación del WHILE, confirma que la entrada es -1 y rompe el bucle, habiendo guardado el valor 0 como último cambio de la variable "contadorPares".